# mp4 streaming problems using azure blob storage

Tags: azure, video-streaming, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I uploaded a mp4 test video to azure blob storage. But the video performance is too slow and takes a while to start streaming.

Is there anything that can be done to improve performance?

The video size is ~ 49MB
http://dzcdn.blob.core.windows.net/dz-cdn-blob/jiju.mp4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure Blob Storage does not support [streaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media) it only supports [Progressive Download](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_download). It is good to have understanding of these. Because it is Progressive download, the player needs to initially fetch some amount of data before start playing it. Although Progressive Streaming, I haven't seen any problems with playing media out of Blob Storage so far (just for the record - the provided video started in just 4 seconds with super quality).

But if you want to cover wider audience, potentiality with slower internet connection, you might want to go and check [Azure Media Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/media-services/). Media Services supports wide range of streaming features including Smooth Streaming, Fixed bitrate streaming, progressive download, Apple HTTP Adaptive streaming (Apple HLS Streaming) etc. And smooth streaming will help with slower connections, while keep the better quality on faster ones.

Comment: It did not start in 4 seconds in super quality. It started in 20 seconds in super quality. I am on 4mb connection and I can watch any youtube 720p video without any pause. And it would be better if you would answer specifically about SMOOTH STREAMING little bit more then telling them to start studying whole of media services.

Comment: Thank you for the advice Asif! If you have concrete programming question, please use the StackOverflow to place it!

Comment: By default progressive download does not happen with Blob, is there anything we need to do to make it download progressively?